# if 文で [ "x$var" = "x" ] とする理由は？

Tags: sh

シェルスクリプトをみていると、

```
if [ "x$var" = "x" ]; then
    : ...
fi
```

のような記述をしばしば見かけます。

`[ -z "$var" ]` や `[ "$var" = "" ]` ならばまだわかりますが、 `x` をわざわざはさむ理由は何ですか？

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Bashのよくある間違い](https://yakst.com/ja/posts/2929)
の 4. を参照ください。
var=-f などの場合、エラーとなるシェルがある(あった)という理由だそうです。

Comment: posix よりさらに昔のシェルで、ダッシュから始まるとオペレーターとして解釈してしまうものがあった、ということですね。

Answer (score 0):

補足で、 POSIX のシェルでは、引数の数で処理が分岐するので、単項演算子や二項演算子がそれ単体で使われる test コマンドであるならば、今回の x escape (みたいなもの) はいらない様子です。

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html